# How to get a NON-standard attribute in IE8 through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, strict

I have an HTML page that has this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

However, the HTML contains this tag:

```
<applet src="blahblah"></applet>
```

(EDIT: actually the HTML doesn't contain the applet. The applet is created dynamically by other javascript code).

Yes, I know that `applet` is deprecated, and I know that an `applet` tag can't contain a `src` attribute, but I can't edit that HTML code.

The problem is this Javascript code:

```
alert(appletElement.getAttribute('src'));
```

In FF and Chrome it shows "blahblah", but in IE8 it shows `null`. Also, `appletElement.attributes['src']` is not defined.

Anybody knows how to get the `src` attribute in IE8 with strict mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

Instead of using `document.createElement` to create those applets dynamically, I use this function:

```
function wrs_createElement(elementName, attributes, creator) {
    if (attributes === undefined) {
        attributes = {};
    }

    if (creator === undefined) {
        creator = document;
    }

    var element;

    /*
     * Internet Explorer fix:
     * If you create a new object dynamically, you can't set a non-standard attribute.
     * For example, you can't set the "src" attribute on an "applet" object.
     * Other browsers will throw an exception and will run the standard code.
     */

    try {
        var html = '<' + elementName + ' ';

        for (var attributeName in attributes) {
            html += attributeName + '="' + attributes[attributeName].split('"').join('\\"') + '" ';
        }

        html += '>';
        element = creator.createElement(html);
    }
    catch (e) {
        element = creator.createElement(elementName);

        for (var attributeName in attributes) {
            element.setAttribute(attributeName, attributes[attributeName]);
        }
    }

    return element;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
                               "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<title>Test Case</title>
<applet id="myapplet" src="blahblah"></applet> 
<script>
var aplt = document.getElementById('myapplet');
alert(aplt.getAttribute('src'));
</script>
```

Works for me in IE8.

Comment: Ok, I was not sincere in my question. The applet object is not inserted in the HTML, is created dynamically with document.createElement. When you set a not standard attribute to that applet, you can't retrieve it later. It returns `null` ever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
appletElement.src
```